# Disagreement between studentized Breusch-Pagan test and the plots "residuals vs fitted" and "scale location"

Tags: r, regression, p-value, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

Given the model:

```r
> Durée <- c(6, 5, 3.5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 8, 2.5) 
> Note  <- c(18, 16, 14, 10, 15, 13, 8, 19, 12) 
> model <- lm(Note ~ Durée)
```

I was tasked, among other things, to verify whether homoscedasticity is true.

After running  `plot(model)` I was able to visualise the following graphs:

[image: Residuals vs Fitted]

[image: scale-location plot]

[image: normal qq-plot]

From the *Residuals vs Fitted* and *Scale-Location* plots, we can see that the line is very far from being straight, which indicates the presence of heteroscedasticity.

However, when I run the studentized Breusch-Pagan test using the command `bptest(model)`, I got the following output:

```r
    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  model
BP = 1.8622, df = 1, p-value = 0.1724
```

The test gives a p-value of 0.1724, which is greater than 0.05. This means that we can't reject the hypothesis of homoscedasticity, which contradicts, at least in my understanding, the output of the plots previously mentioned.

Comment: You only have 9 data points. Very few tests could possibly return a significant result with such a small sample size.

Comment: @AlexJ What do you mean by *significant result*?

Comment: By "significant", I mean $p < 0.05$. As in, it is unlikely a test would return $p<0.05$ with only 9 data points.

Comment: @AlexJ So should I look at the plots instead for verifying homoscedasticity?

Comment: I just think you just don't have enough data to see whether homescedasticity is violated with only 9 data points. Maybe you could conclude a hint that homoscedasticity _might_ be violated but you just don't have enough information to tell.

Comment: @AlexJ What if a similar result was found with more than 9 data points? What would be the conclusion?

Comment: As in, if you had lots of data points, the plots looked like there was an issue, but the test was non-significant? I would probably trust the plot. But I don't really know the test particularly well.

Comment: What are the values 7, 3, 4 placed next to some data points? If those represent the number of values, then you should be entering all 20 value pairs, not just 9.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky To be honest, I don't know what they mean. They were outputted with the plots after running the R commands mentioned in the post. You can try and see if they would appear after re-running the same commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that tests of assumptions are very often "essentially useless" (see: [Why use normality tests if we have goodness-of-fit tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/576487/7290), e.g.).  Box said, "All models are wrong, but some are useful."  In that spirit, homoscedasticity is a model, and the idea that it is perfectly met is implausible.  A test of a false null can return either a correct decision or a type II error (because you don't have enough data).  It is *much* better to assess the apparent magnitude and type of deviations from perfectly met assumptions than to conduct formal tests.  The best way to do this is generally to look at appropriate plots.

For assessing possible heteroscedasticity, the scale-location plot is better than the plot of residuals vs fitted values.  In neither case does it look like you have a magnitude of heteroscedasticity that is likely to cause problems.  On the other hand, it looks like you have a curvilinear relationship between Note and Duree (but don't have enough data to establish that with a conventional degree of confidence).

Comment: *"In neither case does it look like you have a magnitude of heteroscedasticity that is likely to cause problems"* I don't understand. Do you mean that the magnitude of peresent heteroscedasticity is unlikely to cause problems or the opposite?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, it is implausible to assume that you have *no* heteroscedasticity, but the amount you probably have is small enough that it will not cause any problems.

Comment: *"The amount you probably have is small enough that it will not cause any problems"* Can you please explain why is that the case?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, assumptions are never perfectly met.  Fortunately, regression methods are quite robust to minor violations of the assumptions.  Any heteroscedasticity you have is likely to be very minor.  You may want to click on the [tag:heteroscedasticty] tag, sort by votes, and start reading some of our existing threads on the topic to learn more about it.

Comment: I'm aware of the methods used to test for heteroscedasticity. I just don't understand why the amount I have is likely to be very minor? From what I see, the line in the *scale vs residuals* plot is very (not slightly) far from being straight. Doesn't that point at the opposite direction?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, I have not advised you to test for heteroscedasticity.  I've agued just the opposite.  You would benefit from reading more about the topic.  We have a lot of information on the site that is likely to help you get a better sense of the issue.  Regarding your question, whether the line is straight is irrelevant, again, I think you would do well to learn more about the topic.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question or clarify what you said in the post. I'm trying to understand what *you* mean by "*likely to be very minor*".

Comment: I mean that regression methods are quite robust to minor violations of the assumptions and the plots show that any heteroscedasticity you have is likely to be small.  You get this information by learning to read these plots and developing an understanding of heteroscedasticity.

Answer (score 7):

You just don't have enough data to see whether homoscedasticity is violated with only 9 data points. Maybe you could include a hint that homoscedasticity *might* be violated but you just don't have enough information to tell.

Comment: How much data would be *enough* data? 30?

Comment: @MehdiCharife, that's a question of [tag:statistical-power].  You would need to specify the type of heteroscedasticity you care about, how much there is, & the test you would use to detect it, then you would do a power analysis.  The result would tell you the $N$ required to achieve your desired level of power at your chosen alpha.  In the real world, this is not something anyone ever does--it's another reason why tests aren't really good for this task.